# What jutsu did Minato use on Naruto?

Tags: naruto

I wanted to ask if anyone knew what jutsu Minato used on Naruto in episode 442 of Shippuuden. I understand it is a filler episode but I was curious. Minato uses it on Naruto while breaking up his fight with Sasuke. At 6 minutes 33 seconds Minato places a flat palm against naruto and sends him flying. No hand signs are shown and no rasengan chakra ball is shown either.

Comment: When exactly did he use the jutsu? do you maybe have a time stamp?

Comment: Maybe that just Chakra Burst ? Not a jutsu, but just expeling chakra from his hand. Similar how Ninja can jump so high.

Answer (score -3):

its probably the jutsu he is most known for... the flying rajin jutsu... its why they call him the yellow flash. bascially this jutsu works by sending somthing minatos chakra is in contact with to another location using a specialy placed seal or marked kunai. minato has already placed several seals around the village in case he ever needs to move somewhere quickly and he sends naruto to this seal when he places his hand on him... as for the no handsigns minato is a hokage level ninja.... his hand signs are too quick for average ninja to see.